# Los números resultantes no son los deseados

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer la sucesión de Fibonacci, pero no me funciona, por qué?

```js
var Lpisa = [];

for(var i=0;i<89;i++){ // Lo dejo hasta 89, ya que es un número de Fibonnaci, y esto es un ejemplo, entonces para no alargarlo.
  var b; 
  /*
  Los números de fibonnaci son la suma del actual número y los dos anteriores, osea:
  fSucesion = n + (n-1) + (n-2)
  0 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 5 , 8 <- Por ejemplo el 8 sale de (3 + 5)
  */
  if((i-2) > -1) // Si "i", es igual a 0, osea que no es negativo
  /*
  Por ejemplo comienza el "i" con 0, entonces b = i, en el else.
  Cuando i=2 -> b = (2-1) + (2+2)
  Cuando i=3 -> b = (3-1) + (3-2) => ERROR <-----------------
  */
  b = i-1 + i-2;
  else 
  b = i;
  
  Lpisa.push(b);
}

console.log(Lpisa);
```

***Tengo un error en el código, pero no entiendo como podría arreglarlo, quisiera saber por qué me equivoco, y usando, mi mismo código cómo se debería realizar***

Answer (score 1):

El problema lo tienes en el caso base, es decir, cuando i es menor que 2. En la discriminación que tienes (el `if`), hace que no se contemple el valor número 2 y, a partir de ahí, ya todos los cálculos están mal.

Te pongo aquí una solución:

```js
var Lpisa = [];

Lpisa[0] = 0;
Lpisa[1] = 1;
for(var i=2; i<=10; i++)
{
    // Next fibonacci number = previous + one before previous
    // Translated to JavaScript:
    Lpisa[i] = Lpisa[i-2] + Lpisa[i-1];
}
console.log(Lpisa);
```

Comment: Pensaba hacerlo con un array, pero por qué mi código falla? y este no?

Comment: Te paso un vídeo que más o menos lo explica: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOiFTej57IA

Answer (score 0):

una funcion y lo arregla, igual no queda tan bonito pero se puede hacer.
esta si está bien.

```js
function fib(n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return 0;
  } else if (n == 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
  }
}
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  document.writeln(fib(i));
}
```

lo veo mas claro con la recursividad...